# No "Admin Page" link on Facebook Like button on a web page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, xml-namespaces

I have a website that uses the Facebook like button.

I am attempting to get the "Administration" link to show up on the page so that I can push content to people who like the page.

My page's HTML namespace is like:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

My meta tags are like so:

```
<link rev="canonical" href="http://mysite.com/welcome/" />

<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" /> 
<meta property="og:site_name" content="MySite" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="012345678910" />    
<meta property="og:title" content="Name of my page" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description here..." />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mysite.com/welcome/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite.com/path/to/image.jpg" />
```

I have checked the page with the [Facebook debugging linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and it passes without any warnings or errors. I am an admin of the app.

**What am I doing wrong?**

***Note:** I've also tried to put the `<meta property="fb:admins" content="01234567" />` in to no avail. I've also tried different `xmlns` tags and even without any `xmlns` tags.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared that the problem stemmed from having the wrong xmlns tags in the `<html>` element.

I had a custom `xmlns` tag that was sending likes to the wrong graph (I believe...).

The current tags that are working are:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

After this change, liking a page would show up the Administration link.

Thanks for the responses!

Comment: The linter didn't catch this?

Comment: No, for some strange reason it didn't. To be 100% honest, it is really just a guess. We've tried a ton of things to get this working and after the above change, it seemed to have started to work... Could have been the Facebook Gods instead AFAIK...

Answer (score 3):

There is no og:admins tag.  Try fb:admins and fb:app_id tags:

`<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID1,USER_ID2"/>`

`<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1234567"/>`

You'll also need to press the 'Like' button.

Answer (score 1):

1) Are you logged into Facebook

2) How long have you been waiting it can take some time to trickle thru Facebook's Servers.

3) The correct tag is fb:admins check Page Administration on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ -

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID1,USER_ID2" />
```

Also your og:app_id is wrong it is fb:app_id

4) At the bottom of the debugger it will give you a Graph URL click that to confirm the admins are correct

Whats the URL you are trying in the debugger?

Comment: That was a typo on my part... not great for me to get help when I type something wrong! Sorry about that!