# Publishing Updates to Facebook Users That Like'd a Link on My Website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am trying to figure out how to get to a spot where I can interact with those that "LIKE" a link on my website.  I have seen both of these articles on Stack, but they have not helped me.

[Facebook Like Button + Open Graph + Website = Pushing Updates to Likes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582321/facebook-like-button-open-graph-website-pushing-updates-to-likes)

[No "Admin Page" link on Facebook Like button on a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451158/no-admin-page-link-on-facebook-like-button-on-a-web-page)

I have a feeling that the second link above is just not up to date anymore for the new Facebook.

My site is http://www.UpcomingEvents.com.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!  We have some heavily LIKE'd urls and it would be great to be able to get info to those who are interested.

Thanks in advance!

Dennis

Answer (score 1):

I must say, luckily this is not possible anymore. I don´t want to suddenly get stuff in my stream on facebook just because i liked one article/page on a website.

Here´s the info:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/

> With this admin page deprecated, developers will no longer have the ability to publish updates to users who have clicked on a particular Like Button. The REST endpoint to publish updates for a Like Button will also be deprecated.

Comment: Yup, a colleague just sent this to me too.  Thanks for the info!